# Blank row automatically created when sorting in excel 365 - how to fix this bug?

Tags: microsoft-excel

My organisation has recently switched to the office 365 version of excel. 
Since then, every time someone sorts data in excel, it creates a new blank row at the bottom of the real data. So, say you have 7 rows of data. If you sort data you now have 8 rows, one of which is blank.
No idea what is causing it. Have re-installed and ran repair tool but no luck.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What version number of your Office 365? Does this issue occur with new created Excel file or just existing files?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided. A possible issue is that your someone is selected a region that includes a blank row.

Comment: There are no bugs, only features :0 haha. Seriously, though, when you click a cell in your data and before you sort, try ctrl+shift+8  and it will show you what Excel is going to select as your data that it will sort. That will help you troubleshoot. does it select a blank row?